# How to generate a copy of a page from a drop down menu in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing an electronic audit sheet for work, where the desire is to generate a new work sheet each day, copied from a blank master sheet. This part is easy, I have a simple macro attached to a button that generates a copy of my master sheet, places it last in the tab, and automatically names it the current day's date.

```
Sub NewDay()

Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
NewPageName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
ActiveSheet.Name = NewPageName

End Sub
```

What I would now like to do is to give the ability to create a new sheet from a selection of 'master' sheets, while retaining the date-as-sheet-name part.

Ideally, the user experience would be to select from a drop down menu the sheet, and click a button to create the new sheet, or to click the button, be presented with the list of options to select, and then generate.

I am relatively inexperienced at VBA, and this is beginning to go out of what little realm of mastery I have. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting items from a list in a User form, I strongly recommend ComboBox. In Project Explorer, insert a userform, and add a ComboBox and a Button. To create the list for the user to select from. We need to have our macro do ComboBox.Add(SheetName,Index) for each of the Master Sheets. To keep track of everything, it's best to have them declared in an array.

We then pop-up the form for the user to interact with using UserForm.Show. Once the user has made their selection, the select button does UserForm.Hide to close the form.

Since we created the combobox list from an array, the list index of the selected item is equivalent to the array index of the sheet we want to copy.

```
Sub Start()
    Dim MasterSheets() As Variant, ShtSelect As Integer
    
    MasterSheets = Array(Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4)
    'This is your list of Master Sheets.
    'Change Sheet1 and Sheet2 to Sheets("Master1") and Sheets("Master2")
    
    With UserForm1
        .ComboBox1.Clear
        For i = LBound(MasterSheets) To UBound(MasterSheets)
            .ComboBox1.AddItem MasterSheets(i).Name, i
        Next i
        .Show
        ShtSelect = .ComboBox1.ListIndex
        'This is how to get the user selected item from the ComboBox
    End With
    
    'The Selected Sheet is referenced by MasterSheets(ShtSelect)
    
    'Your code from before
    MasterSheets(ShtSelect).Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    NewPageName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    ActiveSheet.Name = NewPageName
End Sub
```

[image: UserForm1]

These are the only lines inside UserForm1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If UserForm1.ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then Me.Hide
    'ListIndex = -1 means that the user has not yet selected anything.
End Sub
```

You may also want to check to see if a sheet with that name already exists before attempting to create it. Otherwise you may run into errors if someone runs the macro twice in one day.

I would suggest something like:

```
NewPageName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
If Sheets(NewPageName) Is Nothing Then 'Only copy if it doesn't already exist
    MasterSheets(ShtSelect).Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = NewPageName
End If
```